# error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so ------ confused ..?

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi, raspbian, scratchbox

I have build my toolchain using following link it have , crosscompiler
c++ support enabled :-----
http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/

I am using Scratchbox & Qemu.

Now i am compiling my code in Scratchbox2, c++ code is compiling but
not able to run it throws this error :-------

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so
```

Compiler version :------------------

```
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ g++ --version
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ (crosstool-NG 1.17.0) 4.7.3 20121001 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

compiling successful :---------------

> [SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ g++ new.cpp

output file format :----------------

```
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.6.3, not stripped
```

Error thrown :---------

```
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ ./a.out
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When i run this command :---------  >>>    whereis libstdc++.so
it shows the library

```
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ whereis libstdc++.so
libstdc++:
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $
```

Even i run ldconfig -v same error is there :-----

```
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ ldconfig -v
/home/ignite/sbox2/rootfs/armhf/sbin/ldconfig: Can't open configuration file /home/ignite/sbox2/rootfs/armhf/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.13.so
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.13.so
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.13.so
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.7
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.13.so
    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
    libprocps.so.0 -> libprocps.so.0.0.1
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
    libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.13.so
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.13.so
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.0
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.13.so
    liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.13.so
    libudev.so.0 -> libudev.so.0.13.0
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.13.so
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.13.so
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.13.so
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.13.so
    libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.1.3
    ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -> ld-2.13.so
    libply-splash-core.so.2 -> libply-splash-core.so.2.1.0
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.13.so
    libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.2.4
    libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.13.so
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.13.so
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so
    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.13.so
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.13.so
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    libply.so.2 -> libply.so.2.1.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
    libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.9
    libformw.so.5 -> libformw.so.5.9
    libsemanage.so.1 -> libsemanage.so.1
    libtic.so.5 -> libtic.so.5.9
    libustr-1.0.so.1 -> libustr-1.0.so.1.0.4
    libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.9
    libmenuw.so.5 -> libmenuw.so.5.9
    libply-boot-client.so.2 -> libply-boot-client.so.2.1.0
    libdb-5.1.so -> libdb-5.1.so
    libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.9
    libpanelw.so.5 -> libpanelw.so.5.9
/lib:
    libnih-dbus.so.1 -> libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
    libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib:
    libperl.so.5.14 -> libperl.so.5.14.2
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ g++ new.cpp
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $
```

Please suggest what to do .... ?

Any suggestion why this error is. Please suggest.

Crosscompiler configuration file :-----
http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/

```
#
# Automatically generated make config: don't edit
# crosstool-NG 1.17.0 Configuration
# Mon Feb  4 10:09:28 2013
#
CT_CONFIGURE_has_xz=y
CT_MODULES=y

#
# Paths and misc options
#

#
# crosstool-NG behavior
#
# CT_OBSOLETE is not set
CT_EXPERIMENTAL=y
# CT_DEBUG_CT is not set

#
# Paths
#
CT_LOCAL_TARBALLS_DIR=""
CT_CUSTOM_LOCATION_ROOT_DIR=""
CT_WORK_DIR="${CT_TOP_DIR}/.build"
CT_PREFIX_DIR="/opt/cross/x-tools_4_13_libc/${CT_TARGET}"
CT_INSTALL_DIR="${CT_PREFIX_DIR}"
CT_RM_RF_PREFIX_DIR=y
CT_REMOVE_DOCS=y
CT_INSTALL_DIR_RO=y
CT_STRIP_ALL_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES=y

#
# Downloading
#
# CT_FORBID_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_FORCE_DOWNLOAD is not set
CT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10
# CT_ONLY_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_USE_MIRROR is not set

#
# Extracting
#
# CT_FORCE_EXTRACT is not set
CT_OVERIDE_CONFIG_GUESS_SUB=y
# CT_ONLY_EXTRACT is not set
CT_PATCH_BUNDLED=y
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_FALLBACK_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_FALLBACK_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_NONE is not set
CT_PATCH_ORDER="bundled"

#
# Build behavior
#
CT_PARALLEL_JOBS=0
CT_LOAD=0
CT_USE_PIPES=y
CT_EXTRA_FLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_SH is not set
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_ASH is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL_BASH=y
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_CUSTOM is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL="${bash}"

#
# Logging
#
# CT_LOG_ERROR is not set
# CT_LOG_WARN is not set
CT_LOG_INFO=y
# CT_LOG_EXTRA is not set
# CT_LOG_ALL is not set
# CT_LOG_DEBUG is not set
CT_LOG_LEVEL_MAX="INFO"
# CT_LOG_SEE_TOOLS_WARN is not set
CT_LOG_PROGRESS_BAR=y
CT_LOG_TO_FILE=y
CT_LOG_FILE_COMPRESS=y

#
# Target options
#
CT_ARCH="arm"
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BOTH_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BOTH_ENDIAN=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_32=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_ARCH=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_CPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_TUNE=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FLOAT=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_SOFTFP=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_HAS_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_LE=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_32=y
CT_ARCH_ARCH="armv6zk"
CT_ARCH_CPU="arm1176jzf-s"
CT_ARCH_TUNE="arm1176jzf-s"
CT_ARCH_FPU="vfp"
# CT_ARCH_BE is not set
CT_ARCH_LE=y
CT_ARCH_32=y
CT_ARCH_BITNESS=32
CT_ARCH_FLOAT_HW=y
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SW is not set
CT_TARGET_CFLAGS=""
CT_TARGET_LDFLAGS=""
# CT_ARCH_alpha is not set
CT_ARCH_arm=y
# CT_ARCH_avr32 is not set
# CT_ARCH_blackfin is not set
# CT_ARCH_m68k is not set
# CT_ARCH_microblaze is not set
# CT_ARCH_mips is not set
# CT_ARCH_powerpc is not set
# CT_ARCH_s390 is not set
# CT_ARCH_sh is not set
# CT_ARCH_sparc is not set
# CT_ARCH_x86 is not set
CT_ARCH_alpha_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_arm_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_avr32_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_blackfin_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_m68k_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_microblaze_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_mips_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_powerpc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_s390_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sh_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sparc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_x86_AVAILABLE=y

#
# Generic target options
#
# CT_MULTILIB is not set
CT_ARCH_USE_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_ENDIAN="little"

#
# Target optimisations
#
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SOFTFP is not set
CT_ARCH_FLOAT="hard"

#
# arm other options
#
CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE="arm"
CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE_ARM=y
# CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE_THUMB is not set
# CT_ARCH_ARM_INTERWORKING is not set
CT_ARCH_ARM_EABI=y

#
# Toolchain options
#

#
# General toolchain options
#
CT_FORCE_SYSROOT=y
CT_USE_SYSROOT=y
CT_SYSROOT_NAME="sysroot"
CT_SYSROOT_DIR_PREFIX=""
CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK=y
# CT_STATIC_TOOLCHAIN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_PKGVERSION=""
CT_TOOLCHAIN_BUGURL=""

#
# Tuple completion and aliasing
#
CT_TARGET_VENDOR="unknown"
CT_TARGET_ALIAS_SED_EXPR=""
CT_TARGET_ALIAS=""

#
# Toolchain type
#
# CT_NATIVE is not set
CT_CROSS=y
# CT_CROSS_NATIVE is not set
# CT_CANADIAN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_TYPE="cross"

#
# Build system
#
CT_BUILD=""
CT_BUILD_PREFIX=""
CT_BUILD_SUFFIX=""

#
# Misc options
#
# CT_TOOLCHAIN_ENABLE_NLS is not set

#
# Operating System
#
CT_KERNEL_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS=y
CT_KERNEL="linux"
CT_KERNEL_VERSION="3.6.3"
# CT_KERNEL_bare_metal is not set
CT_KERNEL_linux=y
CT_KERNEL_bare_metal_AVAILABLE=y
CT_KERNEL_linux_AVAILABLE=y
CT_KERNEL_V_3_6_3=y
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_6_2 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_6_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_6 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_5_7 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_4_15 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_3_8 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_2_32 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_1_10 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_0_48 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_39_4 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_38_8 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_37_6 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_36_4 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_33_20 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_32_60 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_31_14 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_27_62 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_CUSTOM is not set
CT_KERNEL_mingw32_AVAILABLE=y

#
# Common kernel options
#
CT_SHARED_LIBS=y

#
# linux other options
#
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_0=y
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_2 is not set
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSE_LEVEL=0
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_INSTALL_CHECK=y

#
# Binary utilities
#
CT_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF=y

#
# GNU binutils
#
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_22 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_53 is not set
CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_1a=y
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_20_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_19_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_18a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_CUSTOM is not set
CT_BINUTILS_VERSION="2.21.1a"
CT_BINUTILS_2_21_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_20_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_19_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_18_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_GOLD=y
CT_BINUTILS_GOLD_SUPPORTS_ARCH=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PLUGINS=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_BINUTILS_FORCE_LD_BFD=y
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD=y
# CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD_GOLD is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_GOLD_LD is not set
CT_BINUTILS_LINKERS_LIST="ld"
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_DEFAULT="bfd"
# CT_BINUTILS_PLUGINS is not set
CT_BINUTILS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
# CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET is not set

#
# C compiler
#
CT_CC="gcc"
CT_CC_VERSION="linaro-4.7-2012.10"
CT_CC_gcc=y
CT_CC_GCC_SHOW_LINARO=y
CT_CC_V_linaro_4_7_2012_10=y
# CT_CC_V_4_7_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_linaro_4_6_2012_10 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_linaro_4_5_2012_03 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_linaro_4_4_2011_02_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_7 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_6 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_5 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_6 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_5 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_2_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_2_2 is not set
# CT_CC_CUSTOM is not set
CT_CC_GCC_4_2_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_3_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_4_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_5_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_6_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_7=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_7_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_GRAPHITE=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LTO=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_BUILD_ID=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LNK_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GMP_MPFR=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_PPL_CLOOG=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_MPC=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LIBQUADMATH=y
# CT_CC_LANG_FORTRAN is not set
CT_CC_SUPPORT_CXX=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_FORTRAN=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_JAVA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_ADA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJC=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJCXX=y

#
# Additional supported languages:
#
CT_CC_LANG_CXX=y
# CT_CC_LANG_JAVA is not set
# CT_CC_LANG_ADA is not set
# CT_CC_LANG_OBJC is not set
# CT_CC_LANG_OBJCXX is not set
CT_CC_LANG_OTHERS=""

#
# gcc other options
#
CT_CC_ENABLE_CXX_FLAGS=""
CT_CC_CORE_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_STATIC_LIBSTDCXX=y
# CT_CC_GCC_SYSTEM_ZLIB is not set

#
# Optimisation features
#
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GRAPHITE=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_LTO=y

#
# Settings for libraries running on target
#
CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_TARGET_OPTSPACE=y
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBMUDFLAP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBSSP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBQUADMATH is not set

#
# Misc. obscure options.
#
CT_CC_CXA_ATEXIT=y
# CT_CC_GCC_DISABLE_PCH is not set
CT_CC_GCC_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS=m
CT_CC_GCC_LDBL_128=m
# CT_CC_GCC_BUILD_ID is not set
CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_DEFAULT=y
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_SYSV is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_GNU is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_BOTH is not set
CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE=""

#
# C-library
#
CT_LIBC="eglibc"
CT_LIBC_VERSION="2_13"
CT_LIBC_eglibc=y
# CT_LIBC_glibc is not set
# CT_LIBC_uClibc is not set
CT_LIBC_eglibc_AVAILABLE=y
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_16 is not set
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_15 is not set
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_14 is not set
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_13=y
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_12 is not set
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_11 is not set
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_10 is not set
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_2_9 is not set
# CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_V_TRUNK is not set
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_2_13_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_2_12_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_2_11_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_2_10_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_2_9_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_EGLIBC_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y

#
# svn is missing. You'll have to either:
#

#
#   - have a pre-downloaded local tarball
#

#
#   - or have a LAN mirror with a pre-downloaded tarball
#

#
# otherwise you won't be able to download eglibc
#
# CT_EGLIBC_OPT_SIZE is not set
# CT_EGLIBC_CUSTOM_CONFIG is not set
CT_LIBC_glibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_mingw_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_newlib_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_none_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_uClibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_ANY=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_NPTL=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_LINUXTHREADS=y
CT_THREADS="nptl"

#
# Common C library options
#
CT_THREADS_NPTL=y
# CT_THREADS_LINUXTHREADS is not set
CT_LIBC_XLDD=y

#
# eglibc other options
#
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MAY_FORCE_PORTS=y
CT_LIBC_glibc_familly=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_CONFIGPARMS=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CFLAGS=""
CT_LIBC_EXTRA_CC_ARGS=""
# CT_LIBC_ENABLE_FORTIFIED_BUILD is not set
# CT_LIBC_DISABLE_VERSIONING is not set
CT_LIBC_OLDEST_ABI=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_FORCE_UNWIND=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_USE_PORTS=y
CT_LIBC_ADDONS_LIST=""

#
# WARNING !!!                                            
#

#
#   For glibc >= 2.8, it can happen that the tarballs    
#

#
#   for the addons are not available for download.       
#

#
#   If that happens, bad luck... Try a previous version  
#

#
#   or try again later... :-(                            
#
# CT_LIBC_LOCALES is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_NONE is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_AS_HEADERS=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_CHOSEN is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MIN_KERNEL="3.6.3"

#
# Debug facilities
#
# CT_DEBUG_dmalloc is not set
# CT_DEBUG_duma is not set
# CT_DEBUG_gdb is not set
# CT_DEBUG_ltrace is not set
# CT_DEBUG_strace is not set

#
# Companion libraries
#
CT_COMPLIBS_NEEDED=y
CT_GMP_NEEDED=y
CT_MPFR_NEEDED=y
CT_PPL_NEEDED=y
CT_CLOOG_NEEDED=y
CT_MPC_NEEDED=y
CT_COMPLIBS=y
CT_GMP=y
CT_MPFR=y
CT_PPL=y
CT_CLOOG=y
CT_MPC=y
CT_GMP_V_5_0_2=y
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_2 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_0 is not set
CT_GMP_VERSION="5.0.2"
CT_MPFR_V_3_1_0=y
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_0 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_2 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_0 is not set
CT_MPFR_VERSION="3.1.0"
CT_PPL_V_0_11_2=y
# CT_PPL_V_0_11_1 is not set
# CT_PPL_V_0_11 is not set
# CT_PPL_V_0_10_2 is not set
CT_PPL_VERSION="0.11.2"
CT_PPL_0_11=y
CT_PPL_NEEDS_LIBPWL=y
CT_CLOOG_V_0_15_11=y
# CT_CLOOG_V_0_15_10 is not set
# CT_CLOOG_V_0_15_9 is not set
# CT_CLOOG_V_0_15_8 is not set
# CT_CLOOG_V_0_15_7 is not set
# CT_CLOOG_V_0_15_6 is not set
CT_CLOOG_VERSION="0.15.11"
CT_CLOOG_0_15_1x=y
CT_CLOOG_NEEDS_AUTORECONF=y
CT_MPC_V_0_9=y
# CT_MPC_V_0_8_2 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_8_1 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_7 is not set
CT_MPC_VERSION="0.9"

#
# Companion libraries common options
#
# CT_COMPLIBS_CHECK is not set

#
# Companion tools
#

#
# READ HELP before you say 'Y' below !!!
#
# CT_COMP_TOOLS is not set

#
# Test suite
#
# CT_TEST_SUITE_GCC is not set
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you simply don't have libstdc++.so.6 on target. ("on target" means "on the Raspberry Pi".)

If your Raspberry runs Debian or Ubuntu, try `apt-get install libstdc++6` on it.

You can also try to compile your program statically with `g++ -static -static-libstdc++ new.cpp` which should work if you on the compiling system have static libraries to link from.

Comment: Got Error ---->>>  [SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ g++ -static -static-libstdc++ new.cpp
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ ./a.out 
FATAL: kernel too old
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $

Comment: @user1871965, so this is on Qemu?  Maybe your kernel IS too old.

Comment: I am using cross-compiler in scratchbox.

Comment: @user1871965, you should probably mention Scratchbox in your question.

Comment: @user1871965, try g++ -fPIC new.cpp

Comment: added scratchbox & qemu to question.

Comment: Do you have libstdc++ on qemu by the way?

Comment: Error again :----  [SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ g++ -fPIC new.cpp
[SB2 simple armhf] ignite@ignite testing $ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: even i run following command in scratchbox -- apt-get install libstdc++6  -----> same error --->> not getting what to do .. ?

Comment: I am using raspbian image ----->>>   sudo debootstrap --verbose --arch armhf --foreign wheezy \
$HOME/sbox2/rootfs/armhf http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/

-------------------Key add :--
http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository
wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: @user1871965, if I were you, I would try to compile a brand new Qemu.  http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page

Comment: @user1871965, and check here: http://superpiadventures.com/2012/07/development-environment/ or just google on second stage etc.

Comment: already compiled QEmu -------  cd $HOME/sbox2/src
$ git clone git://git.savannah.nongnu.org/qemu.git
$ cd qemu
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/sbox2/bin/qemu
$ make
$ make instal

Comment: something like :------  http://jecxjo.motd.org/code/blosxom.cgi/devel/cross_compiler_environment  how to sort it out...??

Comment: Actually rootfile system i downloaded do not have that library :---
  ----------------- C code is running fine for me.
How to download interdependent libraries related to c++ ?

Comment: If you have debootstrapped you should be able to install everything with apt-get @user1871965

Comment: Please suggest what command to run -- to get out of this error.?

Comment: @user1871965 *chroot* into your raspi root files and apt-get libstdc++6 from within chroot. Also compile new.cpp with -fPIC

Answer (score 0):

You are executing all commands in the host system. You need to come out of the command mode for Scratchbox and execute:

```
sb2 -e ./a.out
```

to execute the file in the target.

Your reply to 'whereis libstdc++.so' is not telling you that the library is present. It is an empty location set that is saying that it cannot find such a thing. Try 'whereis ls' for example to see a non-empty set which shows the path to the command.

To install libstdc++6 into the target you need to issue:

```
sb2 -eR apt-get install libstdc++6
```